# gns3: Order of booting up devices

Tags: boot

If the `Start/Resume all devices` button is clicked, then all routers boot up. However, there is no order. I would like to define which device comes next. What do I have to do?

I've already sorted the devices in the `topology.net` file, but it does not have an impact.